# Difference between multiple IF else condition and logical OR operation

Tags: java, conditional-statements

Are there logically any difference between

```
if (name.startsWith("a"){
   return true;
} else if (name.startsWith("b") {
   return true;
} else if (name.startsWith("c") {
   return true;
}
```

and

```
if(name.startsWith("a") || name.startsWith("b") || name.startsWith("c") ){
  return true;
}
```

I prefer the second one as it is elegant to me. I'd like to understand "are there any differences?"

Comment: Why not `return name.startsWith("a") || name.startsWith("b") || name.startsWith("c");`?

Comment: Because you don't necessarily want to return false if it doesn't start with a, b, or c.

Comment: @martijno, you re right in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case: no.

Boolean expressions with `||` and `&&` use *short-circuiting*, which means that `B` is ignored in `A || B` if `A` already evaluated to `true`. Therefore, the first alternative is not more efficient.

If the body of the if clause gets bigger though, and contains the same code, then you **absolutely don't** want to use the first version:

```
if (name.startsWith("a"){
    // lots of code
} else if (name.startsWith("b") {
    // lost of the same code
}
```

Code duplication is a terrible sin and often the cause for annoying bugs.

Answer (score 7):

They're the same.

The second one is definitely easier to read, and readability is incredibly important in programming.

The rule I like to go by is that if multiple branches of an if-else statement produce the same behavior, I combine them. (Be sure that they're the EXACT same behavior)

Answer (score 2):

They're equivalent, but the second one is preferable as it's more concise - you'd use the first one if the different conditions should be handled differently, e.g.

```
if(name.startsWith("a")) {
    System.out.println("first side effect");
    return true;
} else if (name.startsWith("b")) {
    System.out.println("a different side effect");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both will do the stuff.

And The last and the best one. i.e   **LOGICAL OR**

```
 if(name.startsWith("a") || name.startsWith("b"){
    etc...
}
```

Because in logical `||`

In this case   It's just [short-circuiting.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

> in which the second argument is only executed or evaluated if the first argument does not suffice to determine the value of the expression:

Answer (score 1):

They are logically identical.  The second one is certainly more elegant and concise though.

Of course, neither snippet of code will work because you have forgotten closing braces. :)

Comment: True. I'll change.. My intention was demonstrating

Answer (score 0):

No difference in this case. They're equivalent.